# why the value return from getComputedTextLength() did not change when font-size become larger

Tags: d3.js, svg

[image: The chart]

I tried to set the title centered horizontally by using `return chartWidth / 2 - this.getComputedTextLength() / 2;`

It seems work if I did not change the font-size, but if I change the font-size larger as 20px, it didn't work. 
What I found if the value of this.getComputedTextLength() does not change as the font-size change.

Updated: I set the font-size in d3.js 
`.attr("font-size", "20px")`

Comment: Just use `text-anchor: middle;` and put it at `chartWidth / 2`. Regarding the question itself, how are you setting the font size? Is it CSS, or D3? If D3, how (attr vs style) and where?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you! I set the font-size by using d3 attr.

Comment: Ok. And I suppose you used `.attr("font-size"...)` **before** computing its size, is that correct? By the way, are you using Safari by any chance?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I used the `.attr("font-size", 20px)` after computing the size. I am using the Chrome~

Comment: So there you have it, you need to set the font size **before** computing the size of the text! Anyway, that doesn't;t matter because as I said you can simply drop that `getComputedTextLength` and use `text-anchor: middle`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It works!! Thank you so much sir!